# How do I generalize a list comprehension of this kind in Python?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a integer list say `l1=[a,b,c]` and `_1to9=range(1,10)`. I'd like to get this:

```
 [a*i1+b*i2+c*i3 for i1 in _1to9 for i2 in _1to9 for i3 in _1to9]
```

but the problem is that the `l1` is not necessarily a list of 3 elements. so how do I generalize?

***EDIT***: to help visualize what I'm trying to achieve:

```
 >>> l1=[10001,1010, 100]
 >>> [l1[0]+i1+l1[1]*i2+l1[2]*i3 for i1 in _1to9 for i2 in _1to9 for i3 in _1to9]
```

Comment: Is this Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: @JohnFeminella: since when does that matter? Thanks for the title btw.

Comment: Doesn't `range(10)` return [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]? Meaning your variable should be called _0to9 and not _1to9?

Comment: It might help to spell out what you're trying to achieve, since your list comprehension is a little opaque.

Comment: @JamesAylett will do in a minute.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some basic math might help here. First, realise that `a*i1+b*i2+c*i3` is the [inner (dot) product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) of two three-element lists, which can be generalized to

```
def dot_product(a, b):
    return sum(x * y for x, y in zip(a, b))
```

and `for i1 in _1to9 for i2 in _1to9 for i3 in _1to9` loops over the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of `[_1to9] * 3`. That's in the Python standard library as `itertools.product`, so you've got

```
[dot_product([a, b, c], x) for x in itertools.product(_1to9, repeat=3)]
```

Generalizing that to arbitrary lists `l` gives

```
[dot_product(l, x) for x in itertools.product(_1to9, repeat=len(l))]
```